# email and password validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my `sign in` page I am taking `email` and `password` from user i.e below:

```
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path,:html => {:id => "signin"}) do |f| %>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">
      <%= f.label(:error, "", :id => "errormessage") %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="color: #212121;">
      <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", :id => "tf_email" %>
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="color: #212121;">
          <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Enter Password", :id => "tf_password" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <% end %>
```

And I want to show validation error if user will not enter email and password or enter invalid email or password length less than 6 then it would show an validation error message like below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#signin').submit(function() {
    var email = new RegExp(/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i);
    var inp = $("#tf_email");
    var pw = $("tf_password");
    var message =  $("#errormessage").html("Invalid Email/Password ");
    if(inp.val() == ""  && pw.val() == "" )
    {
        message.show();

        // var emailaddr = $("#emailAddr").val();

        //alert(emailaddr);
        return false;
    }
    elseif( pw.length < 6 || !inp.val().match(email))
    {
        message.show();
    } 

});
</script>
```

But its not working means not show any error message: Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply. Thanks.

Comment: please share the rendered HTML output, OR better you create a jsfiddle out of that and share the link in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your var `pw = $("tf_password");` is missing an hashtag ;-)

```
var pw = $("#tf_password");
```

otherwise it looks good